# Valgrind output showing addresses not code against errors

Tags: linux, centos

I am running Valgrind on my program. It shows me two errors but mentions only addresses against them and not actual code even on a debug build.

Could you pls. help me understand what it says and how to reach the erroneous line of code?

The output is

```
==23002== Memcheck, a memory error detector.  
==23002== Copyright (C) 2002-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.  
==23002== Using LibVEX rev 1575, a library for dynamic binary translation.  
==23002== Copyright (C) 2004-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.  
==23002== Using valgrind-3.1.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.  
==23002== Copyright (C) 2000-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.  
==23002== For more details, rerun with: -v  
==23002==  
==23002== Invalid read of size 4  
==23002== at 0x8AAE6D: open_path (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AB68B: _dl_map_object (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AF307: openaux (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8B066D: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AF5A9: _dl_map_object_deps (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A6459: dl_main (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8B3DF4: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A53EF: _dl_start (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A47C6: (within /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== Address 0x2F8BBBF8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
==23002==  
==23002== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)  
==23002== Access not within mapped region at address 0x2F8BBBF8  
==23002== at 0x8AAE6D: open_path (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AB68B: _dl_map_object (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AF307: openaux (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8B066D: _dl_catch_error (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8AF5A9: _dl_map_object_deps (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A6459: dl_main (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8B3DF4: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A53EF: _dl_start (in /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002== by 0x8A47C6: (within /lib/ld-2.3.4.so)  
==23002==  
==23002== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line  
==23002== at 0x246: ???  
==23002== Address 0x246 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd  
==23002==  
==23002== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)  
==23002== Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x246  
==23002== at 0x246: ???  
==23002==  
==23002== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)  
==23002== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.  
==23002== malloc/free: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated.  
==23002== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v  
==23002== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
```

Comment: I see you are using Valgrind 3.1.1. That's a *very* old version now. I'd recommend you first consider upgrading to 3.5.0 and giving it another try. The new version might give you a better diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

That address looks bogus. Forget valgrind, fire up [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to find where your program is segfaulting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no debugging information because the indicated code is within the `ld-2.3.4.so` library (this is the dynamic linker).

It looks to me like your executable is linked against a corrupted dynamic library file (or are trying to load a file that isn't a dynamic library through that mechanism).